# How to build a block with a table in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Magento 1.x :
I have an IndexController that foreaches over a tables content.
And I have a simple_page.html template.

Now I want to bring the output from the Indexcontroller into a nicely styled block). So that the Items are listed in tablerows or maybe later into collapsibles from bootstrap.

Where do I begin / what would be the subsequent steps?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll try to answer this.

Magento uses "light controllers, so make sure that you are using controllers for routing and blocks for storing data.

To start I'm going to assume that you can get data out of a database and create a model. If not I would suggest checking out: http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-model-database-tutorial-54

So first you need to create a block class where you will get your code:

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_MyBlock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function getMyData() {
        //return whatever code you would like do a foreach over
        return Mage::getModel('namespace/entity')->getCollection(); 
    }
}
```

Then you will need to add a phtml file and you can get your data this way:

```
<?php foreach($this->GetMyData() as $data) : ?>
    <h1>Yay I'm looping</h1>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then in your layout add this to your content:

```
<block type="namespace/myblock" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
```